# Set pipe as the delimiter for Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have one multiple select dropdown, and I want to set pipe (`|`) as the delimiter.

For example, when a user selects multiple options (like Option1, Option2 and Option3) then it should separate (delimit) the values like this:

> Option1|Option2|Option3

Below is my code:

```
$("#granttype").select2({ allowClear: true, tags: true, tokenSeparators: ['|'] });
```

I wrote this in the `$document.ready()` function.

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far.

Comment: $("#granttype").select2({ allowClear: true});

Comment: I wrote this line for applying select2

Comment: Now I want so set the delimiter, for example if i select option1 and option2 from this dropdown then it should seprate the values like    option1|option2

Comment: use `tokenSeparators: [',', '|']` in select2 option.

Comment: I have tried $("#granttype").select2({ tokenSeparators: [',', '|'],allowClear: true}); but value gets stored in mongo db as "granttype" : "Dissemination,Data collection". I want to store it as "granttype" : "Dissemination|Data collection"

Comment: I don't know how to store this with mongoDB is this working on client side? It can works with `|` and `,`  as two are applied if you want pipe only then use `['|']` only.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `option`  [**tokenSeparators**](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tokenizer)

```
$("#selectbox").select2({
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: ['|']
})
```

Comment: $("#granttype").select2({ allowClear: true, tags: true, tokenSeparators: [',', '|'] });

Comment: I tried this, as you said, but it still did not work

Comment: It still takes comma(',') as delimiter.

Comment: Only do `['|']` if you want `|` only.

Comment: Here you can allow multi delimiters. so i write both.

Comment: Thank you Parth for your answer... but still did't work

Comment: $("#granttype").select2({ 
 allowClear: true, 
 tags: true, 
 tokenSeparators: ['|'] 
});                                                                                                                                   this is my code. I wrote this in $document.ready() function,  Do i need to write anyting other than this??

Comment: You should write this in question . Edit your question.

Comment: @JaiminRaval what issue you are facing?

Comment: My question is simple, I want to set the delimiter pipe(|) instead of comma(,). After writing this code which you said, it still takes comma(,) as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

incase your problem is not resolved yet, here is the answer! On older versions of select2 you got to use 'separator' instead of 'tokenSeparators, like this.

```
jQuery('selector').select2({
                            separator: ";",
                            allowClear:true,
                            ...
                            ...
                               });
```

Although as a fall back if you're not sure about the version of select2, the preferred way is to keep both the options, like this.

```
jQuery('selector').select2({
                            tokenSeparators: [';'],
                            separator: ";",
                            allowClear:true,
                            ...
                            ...
                               });
```

Answer (score 2):

For who still looking this, 
This is script that working for me :

```
$(element).select2({
  tags: [],
  separator: "|"
});
```

The "tags: []," must be included, otherwise it give errors
 
Hope it help