# How do I change the delimiter between selected values in select2

Tags: delimiter, jquery-select2

How do I change the delimiter separating the values selected in select2?  I've tried tokenSeparators, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Select2 Version 3.5.2

```
$(".product-autosuggest").select2({
placeholder: "Search",
tokenSeparators: [';'],
```

Comment: check this link https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tokenizer. This stack will help you even better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721014/set-delimiter-pipe-of-select2

Comment: I've used tokenSeparators, but it is still passing the form value with commas as the delimiter.  Maybe I'm not understanding how tokenSeparators works.  I thought it would change the delimiter from a comma to what I specified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721014/set-delimiter-pipe-of-select2 was having the same problem, and it wasn't resolved.

Comment: Has anyone gotten tokenSeparators to work?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: separator: ';' helped for me. 

$("#Categories").select2({
        tags: true,
        allowClear: true,
        separator: [';'],
        ....